Divide titles by the " - " in Wordpress
I wanted to divide a Wordpress post title by the hyphen, in PHP and HTML in a Wordpress page for different div's.
Here's an example of the title i wanna divide "Charli XCX ft. Billie Eilish - Guess". I wanna separate the "Charli XCX ft. Billie Eilish" of the "Guess".
Here's the code I'm using, that i cant make work.
<?php
global $my_query;
$post_number = ($my_query->current_post + 1);
$zero_padding = str_pad($post_number, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>

<?php
$title = get_the_title(); // Get the title string
$token = strtok($title, '-'); // Split the title by the " – " separator
$artist = $token; // Get the artist
$song = strtok('–'); // Get the song title
?>
        
<div class="col center-elements-top10">
  <div class="img-top10" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)!important;"></div>
    <div class="div-titles">
    <h5 class="number-top10"><?php echo $zero_padding; ?></h5>
  <div>
    <h6 class="mt-2 titles-top10"><?php echo $artist; ?></h6>
    <h5 class="mt-2 titles-top10"><?php echo $song; ?></h5>
  </div>
</div>

I've already changed the $token = strtok($title, '-'); but still it wont work.

Have you tried explode?

What do you mean you "can't make it work"? What is it doing now that's not "working"?

I've already tried the explode, and didn't worked as well

It's no dividing as I wanted. But if I edit the title to "Charli XCX ft. Billie Eilish-Guess" it works. But I want it with the space between the hyphen, just like that "Charli XCX ft. Billie Eilish - Guess"

i've already solved it, i had to change the $title = get_the_title(); to $title = get_post()->post_title;
in the end it looks like that:
<?php
$title = get_post()->post_title; // Get the title string
$parts = explode(' - ', str_replace('–', '-', $title)); // Replace em dash with en dash and split the title

$artist = trim($parts[0]); // Get the artist and trim any extra spaces
$song = trim($parts[1]); // Get the song title and trim any extra spaces
?>


start from adding one missing </div> closing tag:

<div class="div-titles">

seems not closed.

It is closed, I just forget to copy here.

I've tried to change the code to that and put the titgle fix, just like that "$title = "Charli XCX ft. Billie Eilish – Guess";", and it worked, but when i changed to "$title = get_the_title();" stops dividing

@DanielMartins that's obviously because it can't see the definition of get_the_title(). As a test you can try defining it inside the same file. I'm not 100% sure, but it's possible that you'll have to use jquery to execute get_the_title from inside .html

i've already solved it, i had to change the $title = get_the_title(); to $title = get_post()->post_title;
